# How can I Mix three rows based on the unique value of specific column SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to write a sql query in Oracle developer to convert three rows to one row and combine the value of those row.

The table has three column.
column1  : NUMBER(10,0)
column2  : VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)
column3  : TIMESTAMP(6)

I combine column2 and column3 together to be in one column.
At first I have :

[image]

I want to combine these three rows base on the value of column1 (which is 41). I want to have one row at the end:

[image]

Could you please help me to find the correct query?

**Edit** by mathguy: The `oracle-sqldeveloper` tag is relevant, because after the right query is written, there is still the issue of being able to see it is "correct" in the Query Result Window in SQL Developer. This is a bit of an issue, because SQL Developer removes white space so it's not clear whether the result is actually correct. This is discussed in comments and the answer.

Comment: Post your table definition

Comment: What you show at the end is one row - but the text in the right column is three lines of text. (This **can** be done exactly as shown!) Is that what you want, or do you want the text to "run", with spaces as separators, so on a very wide screen the text might show as just one very long line?

Comment: Also: do you want the query to present the text lines in a specific order (perhaps the date order)? If so, is there also a date or timestamp column that can be used for the ordering (by far the much better option), or does the query need to "read" the timestamp from the text column (a very poor option, but it can still be done)?

Comment: @Mihai I edited the question with the table defenition

Comment: @mathguy I want the result exactly as it shown. each row in separate line but I want all of them in one row. Also type of column3 is Timestamp, I would like to sort lines based on column2

Comment: I just tested my answer on a standard Oracle table (with different columns than yours) and I believe it should work. NOTE: depending on what editor you use, you may not "see" the newlines in each row. Copy the query and paste in SQL\*Plus (or change your editor to show newlines as actual newlines) to confirm that the query actually does do what you requested.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I added back the `oracle-sqldeveloper` tag, and I added a paragraph at the end of the original post to explain why it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select column1,
       listagg(column2 || ' ' || to_char(column3, 'dd-MON-rr hh:mi:ss.ff6 AM'), chr(10)) 
               within group (order by column3)
from   table_name
group by column1
;
```

(Not tested.)

This will present the text column is a single table row, but it will be displayed as three lines of text.

You will also likely want to give an alias to the second column.

Comment: But it shows all the data in one same line. Can I show them in separate line?

Comment: @Rojin - That is a SQL Developer issue. If you right-click on any one cell (which shows in one line of text instead of three) and select "Single Record View" you will see the text is **really** in three lines. I am researching right now to see if this is a changeable setting in SQL Developer (for the full Query Result Window tab).

Comment: @Rojin - I didn't find what I was looking for so I posted a question right here on SO.

Comment: @Rojin - another thought: If instead of running it as a SQL Query you press F5 or click the Run Script button (instead of the Run Statement button or Ctrl+Enter), you will see the query results in a script result window instead of query result window. There you will see that the text is, indeed, in two lines.

Comment: Thank you, I can see them in separate lines by "Single Record View"